# HTTP DELETE Request returning a (405) Method Not Allowed Error. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-request

I'm attempting to send a DELETE request through csharp, ASP.NET and its returnin a (405) Error. Below is the code that I'm using:

> request =
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(myTargetURL);
>   request.Method = "DELETE"; response =
>   (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Anybody can shed some light on this? is it something I'm not doing from a code point of view?

Comment: Sounds like the web-server you are sending the request to is refusing to honor your request. This might be the case if the web-server has been configured to block DELETE requests. Have you checked this ?

Comment: Yep, sounds like the API does not allow DELETE. Check their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like everything is working properly on your end and sounds like the server you are sending your DELETE method request to does not allow it.

> 10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.